# how do i "link" to a property in another class

Tags: c#, class, properties, xna

i have a class (say `classA`) that contains a string property.

i want to set it to a string property from another class (say `classB`) so that when i change the property into `classA` it changes in `classB` and visa versa.

i know i can do this with functions by using `ref` but when i try it on my class (Constructor) it doesn't work

here is what i have;

```
public class myClass 
{
    public string Name;
    public int Image;
    public myClass(ref string myName)
    {
        Name = myName;
    }

    public  void changeIt()
    {
        Name = "xyz";
    }

}
```

And my main code;

```
string myString = "abc";
Console.WriteLine("myString:"+myString);
myClass mClass = new myClass(ref myString);
mClass.changeIt();
Console.WriteLine("myString (After doThis):" + myString);
Console.ReadLine();
```

when i run it it produces;

```
myString:abc
myString (After doThis):abc
```

is there something i am missing here? why doesn't it change to `xyz`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally speaking, a change in the state of an object should be communicated with an event.

So in the class that has the "important" property, when you change its value an event should be fired.

The other classes should be suscripted to this event and catch it.

You can add the value of the changed string to the fired event so that you won't even need to reference the object when the string value has changed.

You can see how events work in C# on [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

An example of how to do it can be as follow:

```
class ClassWithImportantProperty
{
    string myString = string.Empty;

    public string MyImportantProperty
    {
        get { return myString; }
        set
        {
            myString = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(myString, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }

    public event EventHandler PropertyChanged;
}

class SecondClass
{
    public string MyDependantString { get; set; }

     public secondClass()
     {
         var classInstance = new ClassWithImportantProperty();
         classInstance.PropertyChanged += classInstance_PropertyChanged;
     }

     void classInstance_PropertyChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         MyDependantString = sender.ToString();
     } 
}
```

Basically you have a class that fires an event every time one of it's properties change.
Then another class that is suscribed to this event and every time it gets fired, it does some process of it's own.

Answer (score 4):

Strings are immutable. What this means, is that when you "change" a string.. you're actually throwing away the old one and creating a completely new one. There is no getting around that without using some dodgy unsafe code. ("throwing away" in this context is.. forgetting about it.. allowing it to be cleaned up later by the Garbage Collector).

What this means in the context of your code, is that this:

```
Name = "xyz";
```

Creates a new string reference with the content `xyz` and assigns it to the reference `Name`. `myString` in the caller is unaffected by that.. it is a different reference.

Comment: why does it do it in a class but not in a function?

Comment: Because the reference is the same within the scope of the class. That isnt the case with strings.

Comment: i meant; home come i can pass a ref to a function and if the function changes that value it will be changed outside the function. or am i missing the point?

Comment: You are missing the point. Re-read the part where I emphasized a line of code.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by @SimonWhitehead, strings are immutable. What you could do in this case, is to change your `changeIt` method to take an `out` parameter, and then pass in `myString` as the input, like so:

```
public  void changeIt(out string myName)
{
    myName = "xyz";
}
```

This will give you the output "xyz" after you make a call to this method as:

```
myClass.changeIt(out myString);
```

Comment: ok thanks. i think in the end what i want is not possible. i wanted a class that managed input so that when i changed the value it would automatically be changed in it's original class. this would mean that i don't have to worry about getting and setting the value all the time. is there possibly another solution for this functionality?

Comment: @user3413042 You can use events, it involves a little bit more code but will automate the whole process :) (added it as an answer with examples as well).

Answer (score 1):

You are referencing a string into the constructor and changing its value in other method. So the `ref` keyword works only inside a block of code, constructor in this case.

This code will change the value myName to Name. But after constructor is called myName won't be referencing to a Name anymore. Note that you are assigning Name to ref myName and it won't reference to a Name.

```
public myClass(ref string myName)
{
    myName = Name;
}
```

This will change the string as well:

```
public void changeIt(ref string myName)
{
    Name = "xyz";
    myName = Name;
}
```

I won't write about immutable because other guys already answered. You can do the trick with interfaces like so:

```
class Program
{
    public interface IName
    {
        string Name { get; }
    }
    public class myClass : IName
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public myClass(string myName)
        {
            Name = myName;
        }
        public void changeIt()
        {
            Name = "xyz";
        }
    }
    public class myClass2 : IName
    {
        private IName iname;
        public string Name { get { return iname.Name; } }
        public myClass2(IName myName)
        {
            iname = myName;
        }
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        myClass mClass = new myClass("abc");
        myClass2 m2Class = new myClass2(mClass);

        Console.WriteLine("myString:" + m2Class.Name);

        mClass.changeIt();

        Console.WriteLine("myString (After doThis):" + m2Class.Name);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

It will actually do what you want to achieve.
[image: result]

Answer (score 0):

To change the `string`, make the following changes in your code.

```
 public string changeIt()
 {
     return "xyz"; //return a string from method
 }
```

In the calling part

```
 myString=mClass.changeIt(); //assign return value to myString
```